# Binding to a combo box in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I've got a combo box which has a collection of Country objects as it's source (it binds to an Countries property in the view model).

The Country combo is shown on part of a user form. The user form is populated from a user object. A user object holds a CountryID only (i.e a foreign key to Country). I currently populate my user form by binding the name text box to the name property in my user object etc. However, when I come to the Country combo binding, I'm really stuck.

My binding for the Combo is:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" DisplayMemberPath="CountryDescription"
```

So for the currently loaded user, I need to take their Country ID and bind it somehow to the Country combo? How can I do this, as the country combo does not have a list of ints, but a list of Country objects. I though about using a converter but this seems like overkill as the combo has a country object in its source with the corresponding CountryID that I want.

So is there a way to get it to get the user CountryID property to bind to the Country combo and get the Country combo to should the friendly user name? I need two way binding, as the user needs to be able to select a different country, which should then update the corresponding countryID property in the user object.

Any help greatly appreciated! Cheers...

EDIT

Here's a cut down version of what I've got (I've left out all notifypropertychanged code for clarity)

```
class User
{
    public int UserID 
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public int CountryID
    {
        get;set;
    }
}

class Country
{
    public int CountryID
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string CountryDescription
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

My view model has a Countries property, that is simply a list of Country objects (binding shown above). The view has a text box for user name, and a combo box to show the country description. My view model has a "User" property for the view to bind to. The binding for the user name is :

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameBox" Text=" {Binding User.Username, Mode=TwoWay}"   
DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

The problem I have is the binding for the selecteditem for the country combo. Let's say I have 2 country objects in the combo as follows:

CountryID = 1, CountryDescription = "France"
CountryID = 2, CountryDescription = "Spain"

A user is set up as:

UserID = 1, Username = "Bob", CountryID = 1.

The combo needs to show "France". But if the user changes France to Spain, the user's CountryID needs to change to 2.

Comment: Do you want to get selected country id? please show  Countries structure and the code that you are using for binding

Comment: Hi Syeda - thanks for your reply, I've edited my post accordingly. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Country _SelectedCountry;
public Country SelectedCountry
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedCountry;
    }

    set
    {
        if(value != null && value != _SelectedCountry)
        { 
            if(User.CountryID != value.CountryID) 
                User.CountryID = value.CountryID;
            _SelectedCountry = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't Forget to place RaisePropertyChanged in all required places.
If you have any problems understanding this then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented it as you suggested and it works fine! Cheers!

Comment: No offence, but even though it appears simple and does work that is a really bad solution to the problem specified. You are introducing a lot of code into the ViewModel where a converter is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you needed a ValueMemberPath **which does exist on the combo box**, *presumably as they thought it was not needed*.

Instead each item in the combox binds to a Country item, so what you really need is a value converter that transforms a `Country` object to an ID number/int (and back again if you need two way, otherwise the code below will do the job).

e.g. something like:

```
public class CountryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Country country = (Country)value;
        return country.CountryId;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        /// Not sure yet the best way to get the correct Country object instance, unless you can attach it to the convertor, pass it as a ConvertorParameter or just make it global. :)
    }
}
```

The problem with two-way is that to convert back from a number to the correct instance of a Country object, you need access to the actual list of Country objects used by the control.

Anyway: You then simply bind the SelectedItem of the ComboBox to the User.CountryID property (also specifying the converter of course).

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameBox" SelectedItem={Binding User.CountryID, Convertor={StaticResource CountryConverter}} Text="{Binding User.Username, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

And declare the converter in the page resources like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:CountryConverter x:Key="CountryConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```